# GWT starter project doesn't work when inherit smartGWT is added

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm brand new to GWT and am trying to use SmartGWT. I got GWT setup and created a new project. The starter project that's supplied with the new project works fine, but once I add the smartGWT jars and inherit the smartGWT tools in my .gwt.xml file the module doesn't load.

My .gwt.xml file looks like this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0//EN"
  "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.7.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='whydoyouhateme'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->
<inherits name= 'com.smartgwt.tools.SmartGwtTools' />
  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='com.lmco.client.WhyDoYouHateMe'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Inherit tag for SmartGWT jar will be like this,try this

```
  <inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>
```

Comment: I added the smartgwt.jat and the smartgwt-skins.jar and that line in the module and does not work!